# Parse Server: Multi-tenant, multi-user application and AP's

Tags: parse-platform, acl, multi-tenant, roles, multi-user

I'm working on a warehouse management application that will have multiple companies sharing a common database hosted on Back4App. Each company will have multiple users. For some features of the application to work, users at a given company will need to access data "owned" by another company.

For data security, it is important that it isn't just queries that are filtering back the rest of the results. A company may elect to, for example, make only certain items in their inventory visible to select other companies.

Given the multi-company, multi-user scenario, would "roles" be appropriate? I would have to create a "role" for each company using the system. There could be a few hundred companies. Users at a given company would be assigned to that company's role.

Are Roles the right way to go about doing this or is there another method that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

One of the Best Practices is the control from the user in your Dashboard, Parse Server talk about two important points, that's:

- Class-Level Permissions
- ACL's

In Class-Level Permissions the Developer can enforce security measures at this level will restrict how and when client applications can access and create data on Parse, for example:

- A client application can create new classes on Parse
- A client application can add fields to classes
- A client application can modify or query for objects on Parse

You can read more about this configuration at the link below:

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#configuring-class-level-permissions

The easiest way to control who can access which data is through access control lists, commonly known as ACLs. The idea behind an ACL is that each object has a list of users and roles along with what permissions that user or role has.

I'll recommend that you read more about it, on this amazing guide from Parse Server:

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#access-control-lists

In your case, you need to use both points from Security, using ACL, you can give for an object a read or write permission. Example, the line below:

```
acl.setRoleWriteAccess("admins", true);
```

I was reading here and I check an amazing point from Parse Server, that is the 'REQUIRES AUTHENTICATION PERMISSION', this CLP prevents any non authenticated user from performing the action protected by the CLP, you can read more about this possibility at the link below:

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#requires-authentication-permission-requires-parse-server---230

If I am able to check more links about Security, I'll share with you :)